# M2: How to enable Configurable Swatches on Catalogsearch page

Tags: magento2.2

How to enable configurable swatches option on catalog search?

I don't know why, the configurable swatches color is not showing on catalog search, but its working fine on Product list pages.

**Catalog Search Page :**
[image]

**Product List Page :**
[image]

Configurable Swatches color not showing on catalog search product list.

in catalogsearch result.phtml, I'm including the product list template to the result.phtml. But configurable swatches option still not showing on catalogsearch product list.

```
<div class="search results">
    <?php if ($messages = $block->getNoteMessages()): ?>
        <div class="message notice">
            <div>
                <?php foreach ($messages as $message): ?>
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
                    $message ?><br/>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?= $block->getProductListHtml() ?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create catalogsearch_result_index.xml file on this path

```
app/design/frontend/{{Theme_Vendor}}/{{Theme_Name}}/Magento_Swatches/layout/catalogsearch_result_index.xml
```

And add following code in catalogsearch_result_index.xml File.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="category.product.type.details.renderers">
        <block class="Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable" as="configurable" template="Magento_Swatches::product/listing/renderer.phtml" />
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

Save file and flush cache.